# Prevent row fields from resetting on custom validation

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I'm making my own validation in `material-table` when adding a new row, so it avoids creating a new one with any missing fields. The thing is I'm trying to prevent the creation but I want the row not to close, instead keeping it in it's editable state, with the data the user wrote, so it's not lost.
I kinda resolved keeping the row editable, but when it validated the fields, all the data the user entered resets.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { checkObjectLength, checkObjectKey } from "./../helpers";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import SnackbarNotification from "./SnackbarNotification";

class CustomTable extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    message: "",
    alertStyle: "",
    temporaryData: {},
    columns: [
      {
        title: "Column1",
        field: "column1",
        lookup: {
          1: "option1",
          2: "option2",
          3: "option3"
        }
      },
      {
        title: "Column2",
        field: "column2",
        lookup: {
          10: "option1",
          11: "option2",
          12: "option3",
          13: "option4"
        }
      },
      {
        title: "column3",
        field: "column3",
        lookup: {
          20: "option1"
        }
      },
      { title: "column4", field: "column4" }
    ],
    data: [
      {
        column1: "somedata",
        column2: "somedata",
        column3: "somedata",
        column4: "somedata"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({
      open: false
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <style global="true" jsx="true">
          {`
            .MuiFormControl-root.MuiTextField-root {
              width: 100%;
            }
          `}
        </style>

        <CustomTable
          options={{
            search: false,
            actionsColumnIndex: 4,
            filtering: true
          }}
          components={{
            Container: props => props.children
          }}
          title="Search by"
          columns={this.state.columns}
          data={this.state.data}
          editable={{
            onRowAdd: newData => {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  const data = [...this.state.data];
                  if (checkObjectLength(newData)) {
                    return this.setState({
                      open: true,
                      message: "Some fields are missing!",
                      alertStyle: "error",
                      temporaryData: newData
                    });
                  }
                  resolve();
                  data.push(newData);
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    data,
                    open: true,
                    message: "Successfully saved!",
                    alertStyle: "success"
                  });
                }, 300);
              });
            },
            onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  resolve();
                  const data = [...this.state.data];
                  //Only checking this field since it's the only one that can be empty on edit
                  if (checkObjectKey(newData.value)) {
                    return this.setState({
                      open: true,
                      message: "Some fields are missing!",
                      alertStyle: "error"
                    });
                  }
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    data,
                    open: true,
                    message: "Successfully updated!",
                    alertStyle: "success"
                  });
                }, 300);
              });
            },
            onRowDelete: oldData => {
              return new Promise(resolve => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                  resolve();
                  const data = [...this.state.data];
                  data.splice(data.indexOf(oldData), 1);
                  this.setState({
                    ...this.state,
                    data,
                    open: true,
                    message: "Successfully deleted!",
                    alertStyle: "success"
                  });
                }, 300);
              });
            }
          }}
        />
        <SnackbarNotification
          open={this.state.open}
          handleClose={this.handleClose}
          message={this.state.message}
          alertStyle={this.state.alertStyle}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CustomTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `reject` to keep them remain in editable state

```
onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = [...this.state.data];
      //Only checking this field since it's the only one that can be empty on edit
      if (checkObjectKey(newData.value)) {
        return reject(); // Reject when invalid
      }
      resolve(); // Move resolve below here
      data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        data,
        open: true,
        message: "Successfully updated!",
        alertStyle: "success"
      });
    }, 300);
  });
},
```

Comment: Yes, this keeps the editable state. But what about keeping the information on the inputs? Right now, the information is gone.

Comment: Look like it's have to split to two component to make a table not re-render and mess things up. Here the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/56483708-xdx8p

Comment: Oh! That's right! The message should be sent from the outside in order to not break the statement. Thank you very much!

Comment: yes reject() is the right way to go. however, this still does not solve it such that it should show the fields as having red borders for example if there are errors. Looks like this feature is not supported by default.